# How to format simple if statements to one line in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, format

How can I configure Eclipse formatter to format simple if statement like

```
result = validate(object);
if (result != 'OK') {
  return result;
}
```

to

```
result = validate(object);
if (result != 'OK') { return result; }
```

In other words: Keep If-statements including one statement in one line if possible. I checked `New Lines > In control statements > 'if else' > Keep simple 'if' on one line`, but somehow it's not simple enough though.

Comment: _Simple_ means without curly brackets: `if (result != 'OK') return result;`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this is against my checkstyle configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set ***New Lines > Keep braced code on one line > 'if then' statement body*** to ***If at most one item*** for that.